# RDF/XML using Jena

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena, rdfs

How can I generate the following RDF/XML using Jena?

```
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/A#B">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/A" />
     </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://example.com/C">
            <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.com/A" />
        </rdf:Property>
</rdfs:Class>
```

Comment: <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/A#B">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/A" />
     </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://example.com/C">
   <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.com/A" />
        </rdf:Property>
</rdfs:Class>

Comment: That's invalid RDF/XML because you can't just nest a rdf:Property definition inside an rdfs:Class definition without an intervening property. In general, when dealing with RDF, forget about the XML and think in terms of the *triples* that are encoded in the XML. That's the only way to make sense of it. Remember it's a set of triples.

Comment: OK , just forget about the validity , we can remove the property

Comment: It would be better to post information directly relevant to the question in the question itself, rather than as a comment. StackOverflow allows you to edit your questions after you have posted them. You can embed source code by starting each line with four spaces (see my answer below).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many Jena tutorials on the web. However, what you are asking for is pretty straightforward. Here's one solution:

```
package example;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

class RdfXmlExample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new RdfXmlExample().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM );
        String NS = "http://example.com/test#";

        OntClass a = m.createClass( NS + "A" );
        OntClass b = m.createClass( NS + "B" );

        a.addSubClass( b );

        OntProperty c = m.createOntProperty( NS + "c" );
        c.addRange( a );

        m.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/test#B">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.com/test#A"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </rdfs:Class>
  <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://example.com/test#c">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.com/test#A"/>
  </rdf:Property>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Thank you very much lan , you just post to rescue :)

Answer (score 1):

@Ian Dickinson's answer is spot on.
If you wish to write this output to a file you can use this line instead

```
 m.write( new FileWriter("some-file.owl"), "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
```

You can then view this file either through protege or on WebVowl.

Answer (score 0):

Code + explanation of

- Jena RDF API tutorial
- SPARQL tutorial
- Ontology API overview

http://incubator.apache.org/jena/getting_started/index.html

decent place to start with jena.